# Trouble creating temp table in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

I'm trying to create a table from a join of 2 tables so I can switch between data. But I'm getting a syntax error on "(" and if I remove I and only do "AS" I get a syntax error on the select command.

```
CREATE TABLE Neigh 
AS 
    (SELECT *
     FROM COR_NEIGBORHOODS_N1 A1 
     LEFT JOIN NEIG_RAMAT_GAN_SHCONOT B1 ON A1.Settle_Name = B1.City_Name 
                                         AND A1.NEIGHBORHOODs_AREA_FNAME = B1.name
     WHERE B1.City_Name IS Null AND A1.Settle_Code = 8600)
```

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server does not support `create table as`.  Instead, it uses the syntax `into`.  So:

```
select *
into Neigh
from COR_NEIGBORHOODS_N1 n left join
     NEIG_RAMAT_GAN_SHCONOT nrg
     on n.Settle_Name = nrg.City_Name and
        n.NEIGHBORHOODs_AREA_FNAME = nrg.name
WHERE nrg.City_Name IS Null and n.Settle_Code = 8600;
```

The use of `select *` is dangerous -- because column names might be duplicated.  I would recommend that you list the columns specifically.

Notice that I also changed the table aliases from meaningless letters to abbreviations for the table names.

Comment: ok so I used this syntax and all good but the problem is as you said I have 2 columns with the same name in the tables. this column name can not be changed because it was set by ArcGIS pro, it's a geodata column.
so I cant run the syntax

Comment: As Gordon already indicated, using "*" as the select list is the problem. It is laziness on your part now. A table cannot have multiple columns with the same name so specify the columns you want. Better yet - why do you need to create a table AT ALL?

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE TABLE Neigh AS (SELECT Column_name AS Column1,Column_name AS Column2  FROM COR_NEIGBORHOODS_N1 CN LEFT JOIN NEIG_RAMAT_GAN_SHCONOT NRG  ON CN.Settle_Name = NRG.City_Name  AND CN.NEIGHBORHOODs_AREA_FNAME = NRG.name  WHERE NRG.City_Name IS Null AND CN.Settle_Code = 8600)`

Please use 'AS' for column aliases with the same tables as I have used in the above query.